# Getting negative of CGVector

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have

```
let impulse = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(Constants.impulse), 0)
```

How can I get the negative of it without creating another CGVector?

I was thinking of creating an extension on CGVector to have a method that would reverse it, but I also need it to create a new CGVector, not override impulse.

Also, am I correct in saying that CGVector is a reference type?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `CGVector` methods:

```
public extension CGVector {
   func horizontalReverse() -> CGVector {
       return CGVector(dx:-self.dx,dy:self.dy)
   }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var impulse = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(Constants.impulse), 0)
impulse = impulse.horizontalReverse()
```

In Swift, **struct**, **enum** and **tuple** objects are all value types and objects defined as class **are reference types**. Value type data is copied when you assign it around whereas reference type data is passed by reference and points to the same underlying data.

Never mind the declaration of `CGVector` sources.
In your case we have let or var declaration.

According to [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> Constants and variables must be declared before they are used. You
>   declare constants with the **let** keyword and variables with the
>   **var** keyword.

**let** creates a constant.You can't change its value once you have set it. You can still add it to other things and create new variables though.

**var** creates a variable. So you can change the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

### Mutating a struct

You can add a function extension to `mutate` the `var` properties inside a `struct`. The function will need to be marked as `mutating`.

### The code

Here's the code

```
extension CGVector {
    mutating func negate() {
        dx *= -1
        dy *= -1
    }
}
```

### Example

```
var impulse = CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 2)
impulse.negate()
print(impulse) // CGVector(dx: -1.0, dy: -2.0)
```

The second line of code mutated the original impulse value without creating a new value.

> Please note that in order to use the `negate()` mutating function, `impulse` must be a var.